# update UI component from model

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I am puzzled by the inherent complexity of PySide2 / QML to do the simplest of UI related tasks compared to other frameworks. But now that I am stuck with it, have to go down that rabbit hole.

I have a `model.py` that contains:

```
def update_state_to_running(self):
    """
    """
    self._logger.info('MODEL - RUNNING')
    self.VIEW_STATE = State.RUNNING

@Property(bool)
def view_running(self):
    """
    """
    return self.VIEW_STATE == State.RUNNING
```

and in my `view.qml`

```
DynamicText {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    text: qsTr("In Progress")
    visible:{ console.log('RUNNING');
              console.log(model.view_running);
              return model.view_running;}
    font.pixelSize: 18
}
```

Now, I see the console output when I open the view, the text label does not show - correct. But it does not appear when I run `update_state_to_running` on my model. In other frameworks this would show the label but it seems I have to trigger an event to update the UI?
I am truly puzzled why this is so overly complicated for such a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default property is not notifiable, if you want the change to be notified then you must associate it with a signal:

```
class Foo(QObject):
    stateChanged = Signal()
    # ...
    def update_state_to_running(self):
        """
        """
        self._logger.info('MODEL - RUNNING')
        self.VIEW_STATE = State.RUNNING
        self.stateChanged.emit()

    @Property(bool, notify=stateChanged)
    def view_running(self):
        """
        """
        return self.VIEW_STATE == State.RUNNING
```

Comment: Thanks. And who will listen to the `stateChanged` ? Is there a simple example to this? I am used from other frameworks that this will be done automatically. What do I have to do in the `qml` to listen to that?

Comment: AAAAAH, now I see the connection. `stateChanged.emit()` will be caught with `notify=stateChanged` so it updates then. `stateChanged` is a `model.py` internal signal.

Comment: @ElDude The connection is in `visible: model.view_running` , there you have made a binding but it is only updated through the signal. don't expect the same behavior in the different frameworks, each one has its own particular way of working

Comment: Yeah, I'm perplexed by the required level of of involvement for these basic functionalities.